# S3 generic/method consistency - How to dispatch according to chosen type?

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am trying to build a generic function that dispatches to other functions according to the type of algorithm chosen. In the example below, the type of algorithm is just chosen by a character like "algo1", "algo2", etc... x is an object of class S4. Arguments A & B are common to all methods (functions). I'd like to name the functions called Myfun.algo1 and Myfun.algo2. These functions have some parameters set to some default value, hence the purpose of having a generic.

```
#' @export Myfun
Myfun<-function(x, type = c("algo1", "algo2"), A, B, ...){

  switch(type,

         algo1={res<-do.call(Myfun.algo1, list(x, A, B, ...))},

         algo2={res<-do.call(Myfun.algo2, list(x, A, B, ...))},

         stop("Unknown Type"))

   return(res)
}


#' @rdname MyFun
#' @export
MyFun.algo1<-function(x, A, B, C=2, D=300){

 #Do a bit of magic.

}

#' @rdname MyFun
#' @export
MyFun.algo2<-function(x, A, B, E=10, F=1000){

 #Do more magic.

}
```

It works but when I check the package (with check()), I keep having the same error:

> ```
> checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING   
> MyFun:
> function(x, type, A, B, ...)   
>   MyFun.algo1:
> function(x, A, B, C, D)
>
> #Same thing for algo2.
>
> See section 'Generic functions and methods' in the 'Writing R   Extensions' manual.
> Found the following apparent S3 methods exported but not registered:
> MyFun.algo1 MyFun.algo2   
> See section 'Registering S3 methods' in the 'Writing R Extensions'   manual.
> ```

I looked into the manual but it was really not helpful. I tried changing the roxygen2 tags by adding @method and @S3method, it didn't helped. I tried changing the order of the ... and put "type" at the end in MyFun, it didn't helped neither. I don't understand... what am I doing wrong? Why am I not allowed to do this ? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code in the question `MyFun` is not a generic and `MyFun.algo1` and `MyFun.algo2` are not S3 methods even though the names seem to suggest that. It would be beter to change it to something like this which is not suggestive of something it is not, won't trigger any checks and is more compact.

```
Myfun <- function(x, type = c("algo1", "algo2"), A, B, ...) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  do.call(type, list(x, A, B, ...))
}

algo1 <- function(x, A, B, ...) "algo1"
algo2 <- function(x, A, B, ...) "algo2"

# test run
Myfun(1, "algo1", 2, 3)
## [1] "algo1"

# another test run
Myfun(1, A = 2, B = 3)
## [1] "algo1"
```

Comment: That does not answer my question. You just re-structured my code and it does exactly the same thing. Rename your functions algo1 and algo2 as Myfun.algo1 & Myfun.algo2 and run a check(), you will see, the WARNING meassage is still there.

Comment: The code in the answer does not have the problems you were having and also avoids the switch statement. Of course if you re-introduce the errors in the question into the answer then of course you will have the same problems.

Comment: My question was specifically that: why can't I name my functions Myfun.algo1 & Myfun.algo2 ? You tell me I can't but you don't tell me why... For example look at the baseline package, that's exactly what they are doing: there is the baseline function and then algorithms like basline.irls etc. and you can just call them by doing baseline(x, method="irls"). So obviously it is something possible. Should I define my type as a class ?

Comment: Presumably the checking does not look any deeper than the names so it thinks you have an S3 generic with its methods.  Just don't use that set of names. It's pretty confusing to people too -- not just to the check.

Comment: Nevermind, I just figured out the issue: without knowing, I was using a function name (MyFun) that was already existing in the base package of R... therefore the check was comparing my arguments to the ones of the base function & not the new function I had defined. I changed the name of MyFun to NewFun and now I can define NewFun.algo1 & NewFun.algo2 as explained above... If someone from devtools read this, maybe it would be good to warn the user that the function name used already exists in the base package... Just lost 12 hours on this. Thanks for your help and advice by the way!

Comment: It still is not a good idea to use names that suggest MyFun is a generic with MyFun.allgo1 and  MyFun.algo2 methods when MyFun is not a generic and MyFun.algo1 and MyFun.algo2 are not methods.